# Remove rows in a group by until the last row meets some condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df

```
  id  type 

0 1    A   
1 1    B
2 1    A
3 2    A
4 2    B
5 3    A
6 3    B
7 3    A
8 3    B
9 3    A
10 3   A
```

We can assume that this data is already sorted. What i need to do is, for every id, I need to remove rows under the following conditions

1. the first entry for every id is type `A`
2. the last entry for every id is type `B`
3. the last entry's `B` is the last one that appears (data is already sorted)

I've accomplished 1. with the following:

`df = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x['Type'].iloc[0] != 'A')`

Which removes ids entirely if their first type isn't `A`

However, for 2. and 3., I don't want to remove the id if the last type isn't `B`, instead I just want to remove everything in the middle

Resulting df:

```
 id  type 

0 1    A   
1 1    B
3 2    A
4 2    B
5 3    A
8 3    B
```

example code:

```
d = {'id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 3, 10: 3},
 'type': {0: 'A',
  1: 'B',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'B',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'B',
  7: 'A',
  8: 'B',
  9: 'A',
  10: 'A'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Comment: typo, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: what if the first `A` appears before the last `B` for some id?

Comment: every id should start with an `A`, the rest don't matter whether they're before or after the next `B` within an id

essentially the first `A` and the last `B` regardless of what is inbetween for each each id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you could use `drop_duplicates` with different rule depending on `type`:

```
out = pd.concat([df.query("type=='A'").drop_duplicates(subset=['id','type'], keep='first'), 
                 df.query("type=='B'").drop_duplicates(subset=['id','type'], keep='last')]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
   id type
0   1    A
1   1    B
3   2    B
4   2    A
5   3    A
8   3    B
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try this now. is there any advantage to using df.query over other filtering methods such as df[df[] =='']

Comment: @Sebazz44 I just used it here for convenience in chaining but there's a [slight performance difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71626557/17521785) for large frames.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use masks to slice the DataFrame:

```
m1 = df['type'].eq('B')
# first non-duplicate
m2 = ~df.duplicated(keep='first')
# last non-duplicate
m3 = ~df.duplicated(keep='last')

df[(m1&m2).shift(-1)|(m1&m3)]

# (m1&m2).shift(-1) -> value before the first B (i.e an A)
# (m1&m3)           -> last B
```

output:

```
   id type
0   1    A
1   1    B
3   2    A
4   2    B
5   3    A
8   3    B
```

Comment: Ill try this as well, btw whats 'IIUC'

Comment: "If I Understand Correctly" ;)